# Defining a text view in your activity

Tags: android, textview

I have defined a textview in my xml layout. Now when I want to call this textview inside my activity Java file, I don't know how to do that. Can you please tell me how to do that? Thanx in advance.

Here is my xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bubble_sort"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left" 
    android:text=
"hello welome to your first c++ code."/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my Java file:

```
package com.example.cprograms;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Bubble_sort extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bubble_sort);
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you want to do in the textView??

Comment: i am just displaying some text. nothing else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these lines

```
setcontentView(R.layout.yourxmlfile);
```

and

```
tv.setText("Hello")
```

.....

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setcontentView(R.layout.yourxmlfile);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bubble_sort);
     tv.setText("Hello");

}
```

Comment: and now tv should be used with which method?

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.cprograms;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Bubble_sort extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setcontentView(R.layout.YOUR_MAIN_ACTIVITY.XML)
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bubble_sort);
    tv.setText("HelloWorld"); //Here Setting Text During Run time.

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not called `setcontentView(R.layout.yourXmlFileName)`
method in your Activity. Call this method after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thnxx everyone for your help.